# XML::Parser Perl module is not installed

Tags: perl, xml, parser

Installation was successful and went well in my droplet (using DigitalOcean) but when I view the page that requires XML::Parser I still got this error message:

```
Internal Server Error
XML::Parser Perl module is not installed
```

if I run `dpkg -l | grep libxml-parser-perl`

I got this:

```
ii  libxml-parser-perl   2.44-2+b1                 amd64        
Perl module for parsing XML files
```

which I believed its already installed.

What seems the problem here? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you run `perl -MXML::Parser -e 1`?

Comment: Hi @toto, I got no response when I run that

Comment: That means the module **is** installed. I guess your appli doesn't use the right path to the module but I can't say more, sorry.